# What is under these scribbles?

Tags: reference-request, incompleteness

I was looking for the original paper "Über formal unentscheidbare Sätze der Principia Mathematica und verwandter Systeme I" by Kurt Gödel, and [this PDF](http://www.w-k-essler.de/pdfs/goedel.pdf) is the only thing I could find.

The scanned pages contain tiny bits of writing here and there made by the owner of the copy of the journal. After an hour or two of work, I got rid of the bits completely, but page 22 is a bit mysterious to me. What was the owner trying to do there near the bottom of the page? My best guess is that the owner spotted a typo (or thought it was one) and fixed it.

**What was originally printed under this person's scribbles?**

Comment: Looks like the reader thought the footnote number was wrong at first, and changed the ${}^{53})$ to ${}^{54})$, because ${}^{53})$ was previously used. Then they noticed that the original ${}^{53})$ was correct.

Comment: To the downvoter: what was the reason for downvoting so I can improve the question.